# Cant use jedi vim on imported modules

Tags: python, vim, jedi-vim

Lets say I have the next structure

```
MyProject
|--run.py
|--myclass1.py
|--folder
|  |--myclass2.py
```

Im now editing run.py:

```
from myclass1 import MyClass1
from folder.myclass2 import MyClass2
```

jedi vim works great on MyClass1, but when I try anything from MyClass2 it just shows the error:

```
Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found
```

How to make it complete things on myclass2?

Comment: In your diagram, the file in `folder` is called `myclass.py`, not `myclass2.py`.

Comment: Oops, fixed now. Thank you

Comment: Which Jedi version are you using?
Also `:set omnifunc`?

Comment: The version is the latest 0.9, I just git clone two days ago. Output of `:set omnifunc` is `omnifunc=jedi#completions`

Comment: I have the same issue. I'm also using 0.90 on python 2.7. :set omnifunc is the same as above. Any solutions?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this works, guys. I'm working regularly on these cases. Maybe try updating Jedi to latest master? (there's no new release)