# Using goto with user-defined modules in jedi-vim

Tags: vim, jedi-vim

jedi-vim works very well with modules and functions installed on my system.  For example, if I put the cursor on glob.glob() and hit `<leader>d`, jedi-vim brings me to the definition of glob() in /usr/lib/python/.

However, for a user-defined module where a function is imported with a line like

```
from mymodule import myfunction
```

jedi-vim may not bring me to the function definition.  It instead gives the message "jedi-vim: No documentation found for that" if the modules is not in the same directory as the file I'm editing.  Similarly, typing `<Shift>k` gives the same error message.

Do you know how to make user-defined modules in a different directory work with jedi-vim?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of this unanswered question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31094490/cant-use-jedi-vim-on-imported-modules

Comment: This is working. I've just tested it. The only thing that comes to my mind that might cause this would be a caching issue. Looking at `:mes` and maybe deleting your Jedi caches might help (~/.cache/jedi on linux).

Comment: There are no messages and deleting the cache doesn't work.  Should I start and issue and upload a tar with an example?

Comment: Yes. Add a jedi-vim issue.

Comment: The issue is posted at: https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/issues/637

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to solve this from within vim, the right variable to set is `PYTHONPATH`. See [this doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path).

So if you add this to your .vimrc

```
let $PYTHONPATH .= ';' . 'path/to/distant/file/'
```

then Jedi's goto command also works on the distant file.

The `.` is the vim script string concatenation.